# Initialzing Empty Numpy Array from row of another Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having trouble with numpy. If I have an empty array such as following:

```
genre_vec = np.empty([1300, 12])

and another vector of dimensions 13, 12
for i in range 1300:
    set genrevec[i][] = another_vec[i][]
```

Basically how would I initialize the first 13 rows of the empty vec using each row of the other vector ?

Comment: You could create the np.empty with 1300-13=1287 rows. Then join the other array:

np.concatenate((genrevec, another_vec), axis=0)

Comment: Lol, that doesn't help at all.

Comment: That's why it's a comment (:

Answer (score 0):

Just use a slicing:

```
genrevec[:13, :] = another_vec
```

Here is an example:

```
In [12]: a = np.zeros((10, 3))

In [13]: b = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 3))

In [14]: a[:4,:] = b

In [15]: a
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1.,  6.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 9.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 8.,  7.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: I don't think you get what I am looking for. How can I initialize the first 13 rows using one vector, then the next 13 rows using another, and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all your vectors you can just [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) them:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # Some small test arrays
>>> a1 = np.ones((3, 2))
>>> a2 = np.ones((3, 2)) * 2
>>> a3 = np.ones((3, 2)) * 3

>>> np.concatenate([a1, a2, a3], axis=0)
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.]])
```

Of course you need to replace `a1` and so on by your vectors.

Comment: Damnit, how do I do this in a for loop? I am accessing the vectors from the for loop...

Comment: @ohbrobig Create a list of your vectors and then use `np.concatenate(list_of_vectors, axis=0)`